# What is maximum allowable value of "Max Pool Size" in sql connection string

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, ado.net, connection-pooling

What is the maximum allowable value of "Max Pool Size" in a connection string?

Suppose this is my connection string in app.config

```
<add name="Name" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
     connectionString="Data Source=ServerName;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;user=UserName;password=Password;Max Pool Size=1024;Pooling=true;"/>
```

What is the maximum value I can use instead of 1024?  Remember it is maximum value, not default value.

Comment: I think this falls into the category of "if you have to ask, you're probably doing something wrong" - why do you think you need so many connections open?

Comment: It is a web seo application with 100,000 users gathering various types of data. And failure is not an option.

Comment: Most sites need far fewer connections to the database than the number of users. And failure is always a possibility you have to plan for anyway.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is no documented limit on Max Pool Size.   There is however an exact documented limit on maximum number of concurrent connections to a single SQL Server (32767 per instance, see [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432(v=SQL.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)).

A single ADO.NET pool can only go to a single instance, so maximum effective limit is therefore 32767.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know - 32767
This is the limit of Sql Server, not .NET

Comment: you said what i was able to confirm later.

Answer (score 0):

You may check with DBA connection limit set in database server