# SQLConnection pool size and active connection count in C#

Tags: c#, count, connection-pooling, sqlconnection

In C# it is possible to enable/disable Connection Pooling by using "Pooling=True" and "Max Pool Size=XY" in connection string.

Like: [What is maximum allowable value of "Max Pool Size" in sql connection string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8602380/what-is-maximum-allowable-value-of-max-pool-size-in-sql-connection-string)

Is it possible to ask how many connections to SQL server is active and what is the current pool size programmatically?

Comment: I want to limit the number of connections to the SQL server to limit the load for one application. I want to analyze the current situation with no connection limit in the pool and what happens if I limit it to 4 connection.

Comment: I do not know that much. I have clients that connect to SQL server and I have source that I read from. I am trying to increase the number of threads that I use to connect my source to eliminate the effect of ping time, but I do not want all of the threads to write to SQL server at once, which might cause huge load and perhaps affect responsiveness to the clients' requests. Is it reasonable?

Comment: Let me put it this way; limiting the connection pool is not the answer you are looking for. I would advice that you reframe your question with all this information you just shared instead of looking for ways to limit the connection pool. It looks like this is a [classic xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).

Comment: I found a similar question and answer. It helped me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216007/how-to-determine-total-number-of-open-active-connections-in-ms-sql-server-2005

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use *NumberOfActiveConnections* or *NumberOfPooledConnections* ADO.NET performance counter:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/performance-counters